# Concatenation of white spaces as a delimter

Tags: java, concatenation, whitespace, delimiter

Can someone give some insight as to what is wrong with my second delimiter in the code? When I run the code and separate numbers with a comma, or a whitespace and a comma it works perfectly fine, but when I try to run it with a single whitespace, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at main.Mean.main(Mean.java:28)
```

My Code:

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mean {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main (String [] args){
        // Console prompts use to enter their numbers
        System.out.println("Please Enter your Numbers: ");

        // Creating a String of numbers that will be stored in the 'nums' variable
        Scanner nums = new Scanner(System.in);

       // Making 'input' equal to the
       String input = nums.nextLine();

       // Now the scanner class scans the string that was put into the variable 'input'.
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);

       scan.useDelimiter(",");              // Any commas are now a delimiter
       scan.useDelimiter("\\s*");           // Any combination of concatenated of whitespace is now a delimiter
       scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");      // Any combination of concatenated of whitespace followed by a single comma followed by any number of concatenated whitespace is now a delimeter

        double total = 0.0;                 // Initializing the variable total and setting it equal to 0.0
        double counter = 0.0;               // Initializing the variable counter and setting it equal to 0.0

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){          // While the variable 'scan' still has integers left...
            total += scan.nextInt();        // Make the total equal to the old total plus the new presented integer
            counter++;                      // Add one to the 'counter' variable to keep track of the total amount of numbers

            //System.out.println("Total: "+total);      Commented out code that was used for testing
            //System.out.println("Counter: "+counter);  Commented out code that was used for testing
        }
        scan.close();                       // Closes the scanner

        double mean = total / counter;      //  Mean is equal to the total divided by the amount of numbers
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Average: " + mean);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine because you are just using the last pattern entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the delimiters do not stack up. Only the last one is considered you should use a single pattern like:

```
scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*|\\s*|,");
```

**EDIT**

This should work too:

```
    scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*|\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception kind of explain itself. Always refer the api doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

> public int nextInt()
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. An
>   invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the
>   same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default
>   radix of this scanner.
>
> Returns: the int scanned from the input
>
> Throws:
>
> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer >  regular expression, or is out of range
>
> NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
>
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed